# Rename written CSV file Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I'm running spark 2.1 and I want to write a csv with results into Amazon S3.
After repartitioning the csv file has kind of a long kryptic name and I want to change that into a specific filename.

I'm using the databricks lib for writing into S3.

```
dataframe
    .repartition(1)
    .write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("folder/dataframe/")
```

Is there a way to rename the file afterwards or even save it directly with the correct name? I've already looked for solutions and havent found much.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below to rename the output file.

```
dataframe.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("folder/dataframe/")

import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

val filePath = "folder/dataframe/"
val fileName = fs.globStatus(new Path(filePath+"part*"))(0).getPath.getName

fs.rename(new Path(filePath+fileName), new Path(filePath+"file.csv"))
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: If you happen to be on the Databricks platform you can use `dbutils.fs.mv` and it works with S3.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you mentioned here returns a Unit. You would need to confirm when your Spark application has completed its run (assuming this is a batch case) and then rename

```
dataframe
.repartition(1)
.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.save("folder/dataframe/")
```